# Trying to get setEditable to false but get an Error

Tags: java, textfield

I'm having trouble with a part in my code:

```
public class NumbersJava extends Applet{
TextField tF1 = new TextField(3);
tF1.setEditable(false);
```

The error shows up as:
[The error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lxKW.png)

Why does it come up with this error?
What can I do to fix this?

And yes further in the code I have implemented a:

```
public void init(){
add(tF1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `setEditable()` inside `init()`. You can't execute general code outside of a method.

Lucky for you, the `init()` method is meant for that kind of initialization.

Also standard boilerplate about how Applets are a dead technology that have no use in the modern world.

Comment: Well Applets are good if you want to keep your AWT game up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NumbersJava extends Applet {
    TextField tF1 = new TextField(3);
    tF1.setEditable(false);
```

This is where your problem lies. You have to set variables inside your functions like below:

```
public class NumbersJava extends Applet{

    TextField tF1 = new TextField(3);

    public void init(){
        tF1.setEditable(false);
        add(tF1);
    }

}
```